# The page doesnt display the movies what am I missing

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my XSL sheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="movie" match="movie" use="." /> 
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<title>Top American Comedies</title> 
<link href="comedy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body>
<h2>The Top American Comedy Films</h2> 
<p>Number of Ballots:162</p> 
<table>
<tr>
<th>Rank</th> 
<th>Movie</th> 
<th>Votes</th> 
<th>%</th> 
<xsl:for-each select="movie">
<tr>
<td>position</td> 
<td>movie</td> 
<td class="right" /> 
<td class="right" /> 
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my XML code

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="comtxt.xsl" ?>
<poll>
<ballot id="b1">
<movie>A FISH CALLED WANDA (1988)</movie>
<movie>ADAM'S RIB (1949)</movie>
<movie>ANNIE HALL (1977)</movie>
<movie>BEING THERE (1979)</movie>
<movie>BORN YESTERDAY (1950)</movie>
 <movie>CITY LIGHTS (1931)</movie>
<movie>DR. STRANGELOVE (1964)</movie>
<movie>GOOD MORNING, VIETNAM (1987)</movie>
<movie>HIS GIRL FRIDAY (1940)</movie>
<movie>M*A*S*H (1970)</movie>
<movie>MOONSTRUCK (1987)</movie>
<movie>NATIONAL LAMPOON'S ANIMAL HOUSE (1978)</movie>
<movie>SILVER STREAK (1976)</movie>
<movie>SOME LIKE IT HOT (1959)</movie>
<movie>THE GENERAL (1927)</movie>
<movie>THE GRADUATE (1967)</movie>
<movie>THE ODD COUPLE (1968)</movie>
<movie>THE SEVEN YEAR ITCH (1955)</movie>
<movie>TO BE OR NOT TO BE (1942)</movie>
<movie>WHAT'S UP, DOC? (1972)</movie>
</ballot>    
<ballot id="b162">
<movie>A DAY AT THE RACES (1937)</movie>
<movie>ABBOTT AND COSTELLO MEET FRANKENSTEIN (1948)</movie>
<movie>AMERICAN GRAFFITI (1973)</movie>
<movie>BANANAS (1971)</movie>
<movie>BLAZING SADDLES (1974)</movie>
<movie>CADDYSHACK (1980)</movie>
<movie>DR. STRANGELOVE (1964)</movie>
<movie>GHOSTBUSTERS (1984)</movie>
<movie>HIS GIRL FRIDAY (1940)</movie>
<movie>IT'S A MAD MAD MAD MAD WORLD (1963)</movie>
<movie>MODERN TIMES (1936)</movie>
<movie>NATIONAL LAMPOON'S ANIMAL HOUSE (1978)</movie>
<movie>SHE DONE HIM WRONG (1933)</movie>
<movie>SOME LIKE IT HOT (1959)</movie>
<movie>THE AWFUL TRUTH (1937)</movie>
<movie>THE GRADUATE (1967)</movie>
<movie>THE ODD COUPLE (1968)</movie>
<movie>THE PRODUCERS (1968)</movie>
<movie>THIS IS SPINAL TAP (1984)</movie>
<movie>TOPPER (1937)</movie>
</ballot>
</poll>
```

Help would be great. I've been working on this for awhile now I have no idea what I have wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To start with, you haven't explained what the transformation should produce**, using what rules. Nor have you shown the expected, correct output.

**Some observations**:

1. **The `<xsl:key>` instruction isn't used in your code** and can safely be removed.
2. **This is obviously wrong**: `<xsl:for-each select="movie">` . There is no `movie` child of the document node, so the XPath expression in the `select` attribute selects nothing -- therefore the code in the `<xsl:for-each>` executes exactly 0 times.

**Here is one guess**, again:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
     <title>Top American Comedies</title>
     <link href="comedy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>The Top American Comedy Films</h2>
        <p>Number of Ballots:162</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Rank</th>
                <th>Movie</th>
                <th>Votes</th>
                <th>%</th>
                <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/movie">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                        <td class="right" />
                        <td class="right" />
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </table>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have four colums Rank, Movie, Votes, and %. I want the ranking of the movie under the Rank colum, I would like the Movie under the movie colum, and the percentage under the % colum. Thanks for all your help but I am stuck again.

Comment: How would you calculate how many times the movie was voted for?

Comment: @user770022: I don't see any number of votes in your XML document. You need to explain the meaning of the data.

Comment: I have 162 ballots each have a list of movies on the ballots. I need to count how many times that movie appears in each ballot and display it under the votes colum.

Comment: Say I have the movie Fish Called Wanda, and it appears 42 times on the 162 ballots. I am looking for a way to display that information under the votes colum.

Comment: @user770022: I have answered your new question.